# Why the join table is empty

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I created two tables in Oracle SQL Developer editor whos realtion is Many-To-Many, and I also created their hibernate classes 'TestEmployee' and 'TestProject' as shown below in the code. As the relation between the two classes is
Many-To-Many, however a new table named 'Employee_Project2' was created in Oracle SQL Developer editor to hold te primary keys of the other two tables 'TestEmployee' and 'TestProject'.

Values to 'TestEmployee' and 'TestProject' were inserted through Hibernate as shown belwo in section 'records insertion'.

The problem i facing now is, when I run the follwoing command:

```
SELECT * from Employee_Project2;
```

from Oracle SQL Developer Editor, i get an empty table despite it is mentioned in the annotation of the Hibernate class 'TestProject' as follwos:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Employee_Project2", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"))
private Set<TestEmployee> employeesList;
```

Please let me know why despite there are records inserted into both 'TestEmployee' and 'TestProject' tables, the table 'Employee_Project2' is empty??

**note**:

I have not explicitly inserted any records into 'Employee_Project2' neither through Hibernate nor Oracle SQL Developer editor, because I expect the records "primary key"  to be inserted automatically through Hibernate as the table 'Employee_Project2' is mentioned in the annotation

**TestEmployee**:

```
@Entity @Table(schema = "afk_owner", name = "Test_Employee2")
public class TestEmployee {

@Id
@Column(name = "emp_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequencegen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequencegen", sequenceName = "afk_owner.Test_Employee_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long mEmpId;

@Column(name = "emp_name")
private String mEmpName;

@Column(name = "emp_experience")
private int mEmpExperience;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employeesList")
private Set<TestProject> mProjectsList;

public Long getmEmpId() {
    return mEmpId;
}

public void setmEmpId(Long mEmpId) {
    this.mEmpId = mEmpId;
}

public String getmEmpName() {
    return mEmpName;
}

public void setmEmpName(String mEmpName) {
    this.mEmpName = mEmpName;
}

public int getmEmpExperience() {
    return mEmpExperience;
}

public void setmEmpExperience(int mEmpExperience) {
    this.mEmpExperience = mEmpExperience;
}

public Set<TestProject> getmProjectsList() {
    return mProjectsList;
}

public void setmProjectsList(Set<TestProject> mProjectsList) {
    this.mProjectsList = mProjectsList;
}

public TestEmployee(String empName, int empExperience) {
    this.mEmpName = empName;
    this.mEmpExperience = empExperience;
}

public TestEmployee() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

**TestProject**:

```
@Entity @Table(schema = "afk_owner", name = "Test_Project2")
public class TestProject {

@Id
@Column(name = "proj_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequencegen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequencegen", sequenceName = "afk_owner.Test_Project_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long mProjId;

@Column(name = "proj_name")
private String mProjName;

@Column(name = "proj_desc")
private String mProjDesc;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Employee_Project2", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"))
private Set<TestEmployee> employeesList;

public Long getmProjId() {
    return mProjId;
}

public void setmProjId(Long mProjId) {
    this.mProjId = mProjId;
}

public String getmProjName() {
    return mProjName;
}

public void setmProjName(String mProjName) {
    this.mProjName = mProjName;
}

public String getmProjDesc() {
    return mProjDesc;
}

public void setmProjDesc(String mProjDesc) {
    this.mProjDesc = mProjDesc;
}

public Set<TestEmployee> getEmployeesList() {
    return employeesList;
}

public void setEmployeesList(Set<TestEmployee> employeesList) {
    this.employeesList = employeesList;
}

public TestProject(String projName, String projDesc) {
    this.mProjName = projName;
    this.mProjDesc = projDesc;
}

public TestProject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

**records insertion**

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    /*empAhmad*/
    TestEmployee empAhmad = new TestEmployee();
    TestProject projRoadSteepnessEstimation = new TestProject();
    TestProject projObjectTrackingUsingLIDAR = new TestProject();
    TestProject projSalientRegionDetector = new TestProject();
    TestProject projAutonomousNavigationUsingGNSSSensors = new TestProject();
    Set<TestProject> empAhmadProjLists = new HashSet<>();

    empAhmad.setmEmpName("Ahmad");
    empAhmad.setmEmpExperience(9);

    projRoadSteepnessEstimation.setmProjName("Road Steepness Est");
    projRoadSteepnessEstimation.setmProjDesc("Kalman Filter, Java");
    empAhmadProjLists.add(projRoadSteepnessEstimation);

    projObjectTrackingUsingLIDAR.setmProjName("Object Tracking LIDAR");
    projObjectTrackingUsingLIDAR.setmProjDesc("C++, OpenCV");
    empAhmadProjLists.add(projObjectTrackingUsingLIDAR);

    projSalientRegionDetector.setmProjName("Salient Region Detector");
    projSalientRegionDetector.setmProjDesc("Java, OpenCV");
    empAhmadProjLists.add(projSalientRegionDetector);

    projAutonomousNavigationUsingGNSSSensors.setmProjName("Autonomous Navigation GNSS");
    projAutonomousNavigationUsingGNSSSensors.setmProjDesc("Android, Kalman Filter");
    empAhmadProjLists.add(projAutonomousNavigationUsingGNSSSensors);

    empAhmad.setmProjectsList(empAhmadProjLists);

    /*empAmr*/
    TestEmployee empAmr = new TestEmployee();
    TestProject projKalmanForOnlineEstimation = new TestProject();
    TestProject projNonLinearControlAndFiltering = new TestProject();
    TestProject projAppForHydrolicProcess = new TestProject();
    Set<TestProject> empAmrProjList = new HashSet<>();

    empAmr.setmEmpName("Amr");
    empAmr.setmEmpExperience(5);

    projKalmanForOnlineEstimation.setmProjName("Kalman For Online Estimation");
    projKalmanForOnlineEstimation.setmProjDesc("Kalman Filter, Java, C++");
    empAmrProjList.add(projKalmanForOnlineEstimation);

    projNonLinearControlAndFiltering.setmProjName("Non-Linear Control And Filtering");
    projNonLinearControlAndFiltering.setmProjDesc("C++, wavelet analysis");
    empAmrProjList.add(projNonLinearControlAndFiltering);

    projAppForHydrolicProcess.setmProjName("App For Hydrolic Process");
    projAppForHydrolicProcess.setmProjDesc("Android, OpenCV, C++");
    empAmrProjList.add(projAppForHydrolicProcess);

    empAmr.setmProjectsList(empAmrProjList);

    /*empAli*/
    TestEmployee empAli = new TestEmployee();
    Set<TestProject> empAliProjList = new HashSet<>();

    empAli.setmEmpName("Ali");
    empAli.setmEmpExperience(7);

    empAliProjList.add(projAutonomousNavigationUsingGNSSSensors);
    empAliProjList.add(projObjectTrackingUsingLIDAR);
    empAliProjList.add(projKalmanForOnlineEstimation);
    empAliProjList.add(projAppForHydrolicProcess);

    empAli.setmProjectsList(empAliProjList);

    session.persist(empAhmad);
    session.persist(empAmr);
    session.persist(empAli);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: no i have not inserted any records to 'Employee_Project2' at all..and i expect that the values to be inserted automatically into it through hibernate because the table 'Employee_Project2' was mentioned in the annotation...do i understand it right??

Comment: Sorry, deleted my previous comment. But yea, with `Employee_Project2` annotation you've defined, it'll only help you fetch the existing records and allow you to manipulate them as a whole. So when you delete or edit something in `Employee_Project2` object, the childs will get updated when you commit it. Since you've not created any records right now, there isn't any "link" between those records you inserted as hibernate fails to find them and hibernate doesn't assume and insert it for you.

Comment: @SamuelKok but both of 'TestEmployee' and 'TestProject' contains records while Employee_Project2 is still empty??!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never inserted anything in the owning side tof the association: `Project.employeesList`. As simple as that.

You only populated the inverse side of the association: `Employee.mProjectsList`, but Hibernate only cares about the owning side.

Comment: hi...maybe this a question for you as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848443/how-to-query-the-join-table-using-hibernate