# how to query the join table using hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have created three tables in Oracle SQL Developer namely

`1.Test_Employee2`
`2.Test_Project2`
`3.Employee_Project2`.
The table `Employee_Project2` is the join table as the relation between `Test_Project2` and `Employee_Project2` is `Many-To-Many`.
In hibernate I created to two hibernate classes `TestEmployee` and `TestProject` for `Test_Project2` and `Employee_Project2` tables respectively,
and the table `Employee_Project2` was defined in `TestProject` hibernate class as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "Employee_Project2", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"))
private Set<TestEmployee> employeesList;
```

I populated the tables `Test_Project2` and `Employee_Project2` with some records, and the join table `Employee_Project2` automatically got populated with some records.
now the problem I am facing currently is, I want to use a simple select statement on the join table `Employee_Project2` using hiberante as follows:

```
String hql = "FROM Employee_Project2";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List results = query.list();

    for (Object row : results) {
        //what to do here
    }
```

how can I do that despite the join table 'Employee_Project2' is not a hibernate class.?

**update**:

I would like to retrieve all the records in the hibernate table "TestProject", so i wrote the following code

```
String hql = "FROM TestProject";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
System.out.println("results.get(0)" + results.get(0).toString());
```

now the problem is, at run time i receive something like the following

```
results.get(0)msc.hibernate.persistence.TestProject@12ec9534
```

how can i get the values contained in the each row??

Comment: why do you want to do this, you can select all projects with fetch eager and you will get all the related employees , same for projects if you have a bidirectional mapping

Comment: @AmerQarabsa would you please provide an example

Comment: so how does mysql and sql-server are related to this question ?

Comment: you seem to be asking a question that is the result of an X/Y problem. You want X but you're asking Y. I would ask about X. What is that you want to achieve? What data do you want to interrogate? I can't imagine it is all the data in that join table, because then you'll be facing the same entities potentially multiple times. Do you for example want to interrogate which projects an employee belongs to?

Comment: @Gimby i want, for example, to retrieve all records in the join tbale "Employee_Project2"

Comment: all that `Employee_Project2` will contain is two columns: with database ID numbers in them.  I'd say that's pretty useless to you.  What are you planning to do after that?  Query the database again to fetch the objects with those IDs?  In which case, let hibernate do that for you, and ask it the right query to start with.

Comment: @user2121 why would you want to select from join table? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @Antoniossss because actually i am a newbie to Hibernate and I am testing the avialble commands in hibernate...

Comment: @user2121 but it is something you normally never do, so I am asking why would you even want such functionality? There is no reason to try to cross a river with a bicycle, if you have motorboat available.

Comment: @Antoniossss please see the update section

Comment: @MrSpoon please see the update section

Comment: @user2121 that is how `toString()` works... this has nothing to do with join tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to create typed query. With proper mapping you can get related objects as well - no need to query join tables as `ORM` will do this for you:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<TestProject> results = query.list();

for (TestProject row : results) {
    //what to do here
    // do whatever you want
}
```

And with propper relation mapping you can get relations like this:

```
for (TestProject row : results) {
    Set<TestEmployee> employees=row.getEmployeesList();
    // do more work.
}
```

As for "how to"s - the topic is too broad to cover it in single answer etc. but you should be able to start from here - http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/

Comment: but actually it did not work when i parametrized the Query as shown in your answer..it works when it is like this: String hql = "FROM TestProject";
  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  List<TestProject> results = query.list();

Comment: @user2121 indeed, iv took it from `JPA` ;(